# KDE Plasma crashes after installing 7zip .msi version in wine

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I have succesfully installed wine 3.0.1 from the ubuntu repository. After this, I imported a regestry file to make the interface lookm somewhat decent. It is available [here](https://store.kde.org/p/1259774/).

After installing this, I downloaded the 7zip MSI installer from their website. A few seconds after installing this, the screen went completely black, apart from the cursor which I could still move around.

I have seen a lot of other bug reports online about this black screen with the only cursor showing but I haven't seen any after installing an application in wine. I have tested this multiple times with the same results. I have Kubuntu 18.04 installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is not really Ubuntu related, if you insist on running the Windows version of 7zip via Wine, I suggest you hit a Wine related forum.

if your goal is only to add 7zip support to your system, I recommend you install those packages instead

`sudo apt install liblzma5 p7zip p7zip-full`

`ark` should even be able to open them, but worse case you got the command line.

hope this helps.